# If I took a photo of a celebrity do I need their permission to share the photo on my blog?

Tags: blog, permission

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Celebrity photographies copyrights](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8117/celebrity-photographies-copyrights)

My sister & I took a picture with  a pro bull rider, do I need their permission to share the photo on my blog? (I also included their names in the post)

Comment: See http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8117/celebrity-photographies-copyrights for some details. I think this is a duplicate, but the immediate answer is that you can probably post it.

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate, as the question linked by John should definitely have your answers.

Answer (score 2):

If you took the photo in a public place where cameras are allowed and you are not using the image for commercial purposes then I can't see any reason you couldn't post the image. If you are trying to sell it or use it to promote something, that would be entirely different.